# W3 Total Cache can't create files

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I want to use W3 Total Cache plugin. Installed plugin succesfully but i'm trying to enable Page Caching and i'm getting this error :

> Page caching is not available:
>   advanced-cache.php is not installed.
>   Either the
>   /home/content/92/7450992/html/wp-content
>   directory is not write-able or you
>   have another caching plugin installed.
>   This error message will automatically
>   disappear once the change is
>   successfully made.

Plugin can't create advanced-cache.php to wp-content. wp-content's CHMOD is 777 but still same error.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem I used WP-supercache before i installed W3TC.. I uninstalled WP-SC, No solution yet,

Comment: Did you verify to see if the entire `/wp-content/w3tc/` folder is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had you verified that there is no `advanced-cache.php` already there from another plugin (or as leftover of one)?

You can try to copy this file manually from W3TC folder: `wp-content\plugins\w3-total-cache\wp-content\`

Comment: there is no `advanced-cache.php` file.

Comment: @Eray what about copying it manually from W3TC?